# Creating invisible NSWindow on top of a modal

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm coding a plugin and am a huge beginner in Cocoa ; the host displays a modal dialog and calls my plugin there. I want to create an invisible NSWindow on top of that modal dialog (this NSWindow will be used to create a new wxWidgets modal dialog).

But the thing is, no matter what code I write, it's always displaying a fixed size blank borderless window that is underneath the host modal dialog...

Here's what I've tried :

```
    NSWindow *myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frameRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO ]; //
    [myWindow setFrame:frameRect display:YES];
    [myWindow setFrame:NSMakeRect(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f) display:YES animate:YES];


    NSRect frame = [myWindow frame];
    frame.size = NSMakeSize (0.0, 0.0);
    [myWindow setFrame: frame display: NO animate: NO];

    [myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [myWindow setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
    [myWindow setLevel:CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey)];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

If I do this :

```
[[myWindow contentView] setIsVisible:NO];
    for (NSView *view in [[myWindow contentView] subviews]) {
      [view setHidden:YES];
    }
```

Then the original native moda disappears. I don't have access to the original NSWindow used to create the host native modal. What I need for myWindow is to be over the top (like a modal) and be invisible / transparent or 1 pixel wide.

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: There are 4 window levels defined above NSStatusWindowLevel: NSDockWindowLevel, NSModalPanelWindowLevel, NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel, and NSScreenSaverWindowLevel.  Perhaps one of those....

Comment: Thanks ! That made me think about that Cocoa stuff and I found my bug in the library I'm using :)